# Concerning Whether a Certain Property of the Trace is Preserved Under $*$-homomorphisms.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, trace

Let's suppose we a have a $*$-homomorphism $\varphi\colon C(S^{2},M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))\to M_{m}(\mathbb{C})$, where $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. It is a standard fact that for any projection $p\in C(S^{2},M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$, the trace $\operatorname{Tr}(p(x))$ is independent of $x\in S^{2}$. My question is:

> Suppose I have two projections $p,q\in C(S^{2},M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$
>   with $\operatorname{Tr}(p(x))=\operatorname{Tr}(q(x))$. Is it true
>   that $\operatorname{Tr}(\varphi(p))=\operatorname{Tr}(\varphi(q))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, by the first isomorphism theorem, 
$$\tag{1}
\text{Im}\,\varphi\simeq C(S^2,M_n(\mathbb C))/\ker\varphi.
$$
The left-hand-side is simple, so $\ker\varphi$ is maximal. As $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is simple, all ideals are given by compact subsets of $S^2$, so there exists $s_0\in S^2$ such that $$\ker\varphi=\{f:\ f(s_0)=0\}.$$ Then the classes in the quotient are determined by their value on $s_0$, and we deduce that 
$$\tag{2}
C(S^2,M_n(\mathbb C))/\ker\varphi\simeq M_n(\mathbb C).
$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, the image of $\varphi$ is isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

By the uniqueness of the trace (as a tracial state) in $M_n(\mathbb C)$, we get from the two isomorphisms $(1)$ and $(2)$ that 
$$
\text{Tr}\,(\varphi(p))=\text{Tr}\,(p(s_0)).
$$
Thus
$$
\text{Tr}\,(\varphi(q))=\text{Tr}\,(q(s_0))=\text{Tr}\,(p(s_0))=\text{Tr}\,(\varphi(p)). 
$$